# What's wrong with the following Lexer import?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I keep getting an error that I can't seem to understand in my separated parser + grammar files as follows:

[image]

The errors occurs here:

```
# TestParser.g4
parser grammar TestParser;
options {tokenVocab=TestLexer;}
root:  NUM EOF;
       ~~~~ <-- error
```

```
# TestLexer.g4
lexer grammar TestLexer;
NUM  : [0-9]+;
```

What issue am I failing to see?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: @kaby76 VS Code. I think it might have been a caching issue. I deleted all the files and then it seemed to work. Does it look like there's a bug in my grammar or perhaps just in the caching?

Comment: Your grammar looks fine. Looks like a bug in the extension.